# Passing variables in for loop (html+javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, for-loop

I'm trying to read values in an array one by one in order to extract the minimum and maximum. I've tried the following solution for minimum and I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I have tried to break it down bit by bit and it seems that the variable MIN is not being passed on to the for loop

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
 var MIN=Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
   for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
     var tmpval = results.features[i].properties.con;
     if (tmpval < MIN) {
       MIN=tmpval;
     }
   }

 [do something with MIN]
}
```

Comment: Did you look at tmpval ? undefined or NaN would explain it.

Comment: Any reason you're not using [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)?

Comment: By the looks of it, the loop *can* see `MIN`. Which part of the loop does not see it?

Comment: dystroy - tmpval works perfect if I just loop it through the values and store the value each time. It outputs the last value in the array.

Comment: There is no block-scope in js, so there is no reason why `MIN` should not be available inside the loop. Something else is wrong here.

Comment: Juhana - Tried and failed. The array stores more data than just the values im looking for so I couldn't extract the min of 1 "column"

Comment: Joseph - I tried declaring tmpval outside the for loop and writing tmpval = ...; in the for loop. This also gives and error so I'm blaming all on the passing on of the variables

Comment: You're not passing anything in the code we see. There is only one scope here.

Comment: I've also tried setting MIN inside the for loop using if (i=1) {var MIN=results.features[i].properties.con;} ... Still nothing

Comment: That would bee the same (only less readable). But be careful : `if (i==0)`, no `if(i=1)`.

Comment: yes, typo. Actual is `if (i==1) {var MIN=results.features[1].properties.con;}`

Comment: Please build a minimal testable fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com).

Comment: Tried it on jsbin.com and it seems that it's working! I was using Try it Editor v1.6 from w3schools to construct my website and that was giving me the error. Strange! Thanks for helping out

Comment: Can I accept this comment as the answer ? New to this website, sorry

Comment: Developing in the W3Schools Try It Editor was your first mistake... Please use a text editor and browser!